# Unknown property

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, custom-controller

Why am I getting the following error?

```
Unknown property
```

Controller Extension

```
public class CrewWorkDetailController{

    public final Installation__c installation ;

    public CrewWorkDetailController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        this.installation = (Installation__c) stdController.getRecord() ;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<apex:page standardController="Installation__c" extensions="CrewWorkDetailController">
    {!installation.Name}
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't defined a getter for your `Installation__c` instance variable. Try replacing this line

`public final Installation__c installation ;`

with

`public final Installation__c installation {get; private set;}`

This will allow the VF page to be able to access the `installation` variable.

Comment: It should be noted that Visualforce *requires* a public getter or setter to access the variable; it's not enough to simply mark the member as public.